# How do I make a view scrollable in an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

What I tried so far:

In createPartControl:

```
ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        sc.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
        sc.setExpandVertical(true);
        sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        sc.setSize(ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.WIDTH, ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.HEIGHT);
        final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(sc, SWT.TOP);
```

but this does not work. My problem is that if I resize my program window the scrollbars does not appear in my view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Javadoc of ScrolledComposite](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html) describes the two ways to use it, including example code. To sum them up:

1. You either set the size of the control/composite contained in your `ScrolledComposite` on the control/composite itself
2. Or you tell your `ScrolledComposite` the minimum size to use for its content.

Currently, you're doing neither. You're setting the size on the `ScrolledComposite`, but unless you don't use a layout manager, that doesn't make much sense. In any case, see the above link for some official example code.

Comment: Great thanks! Now I learned to ALWAYS check javadoc before asking dumb questions...

Answer (score 8):

Typically in Eclipse views, I want my controls to grab all available space, and only show scrollbars, if otherwise a control would shrink below a usable size.

The other answers are perfectly valid, but I wanted to add a full example of a `createPartControl` method (Eclipse e4).

```
@PostConstruct
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    sc.setContent(composite);

    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Foo");

    Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI);
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).hint(400, 400).applyTo(text);

    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
}
```

Note that `.fillDefaults()` implies `.align(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL)`.

I commonly use this pattern, so I created the following little helper method:

```
public static ScrolledComposite createScrollable(Composite parent, Consumer<Composite> scrollableContentCreator) {
    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    sc.setContent(composite);

    scrollableContentCreator.accept(composite);

    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    return sc;
}
```

Thanks to Java 8 lambdas, you can now implement new scrollable composites in a very compact way:

```
    createScrollable(container, composite -> {
        composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        // fill composite with controls
    });
```

Comment: I get the same result with or without the call to `setMinSize` which seems weird... The scrollbars appear when my editor gets smaller than the size hint in the `GridData` either way. Maybe this has to do with the fact that it is a multi-page Forms editor...

Answer (score 4):

This is a small piece of code which worked for me:

```
    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    Composite composite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    sc.setContent(composite);

    Label lblRelation = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
    lblRelation.setBounds(10, 13, 74, 15);
    lblRelation.setText("Label name:");
    composite.setSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```