# Eclipse view scroll

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have implemented an Eclipse view. The problem is that when the content is taller than the view height the bottom is depicted and you always have to scroll it up. I'd like to change it programmatically and have the scroll bar positioned at the top. 
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried the call `setScrollPosition()` of the Scroll Panel?

Comment: do I have it? I am inside a ViewPart

Comment: This question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698162/452775) seems highly related, on the border of being a duplicate.