# No Scroll on View in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, view, scroll, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am supposed to create a scroll bar in my Eclipse RCP view and I referred to the [`ScrolledComposite` javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FScrolledComposite.html) and taking help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791696/how-do-i-make-a-view-scrollable-in-an-eclipse-rcp-application).

```
private void createComposite2(final Composite parent,final String text, int compositeNumber)
{
    final ScrolledComposite rightScrolled = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL|SWT.BORDER);
    group=GUIToolkit.newGroup(rightScrolled, SWT.NONE, text, null);
    rightScrolled.setContent(group);
    group.setLayout(new FillLayout());      
    rightScrolled.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    rightScrolled.setExpandVertical(true);  
    group.setSize(group.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));         
    group.setBackground(white);
    createPartControl(group,compositeNumber);
}
```

But instead the scroll is absent. Can anybody tell me what exactly is the problem? In one of the online resources I saw `addControlListner`. Will that help? If yes, how can I use it?

After some research and hit and trial, i came up with this code,

```
private void createComposite2(final Composite parent,final String text, int compositeNumber)
{
  final ScrolledComposite rightScrolled = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL);
  group=GUIToolkit.newGroup(rightScrolled, SWT.NONE, text, null);
  rightScrolled.setContent(group);
  rightScrolled.setExpandHorizontal(true);
  rightScrolled.setExpandVertical(true);
  rightScrolled.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
  public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
  org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle r = rightScrolled.getClientArea();
  rightScrolled.setMinSize(group.computeSize(r.width, SWT.DEFAULT));
  }
  });
  group.setLayout(new FillLayout());
  group.setBackground(white);
  createPartControl(group,compositeNumber);
 }
```

which resulted in scroll coming but it would not readjust to show the window. 
Have a look at the first composite with name SOAD. It's the normal size.
[image]
and now this is when i push it on left side, the scroll should have been activated, and it is not... It is cropping the content.

**How do i fix this**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use one of the [SWT Snippets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) (search for 'ScrolledComposite') as a starting point and learn how to use the widget?

Comment: @greg-449 can you answer this?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Thanx for the tutorials but i am stuck here now. what to do ?

Comment: I think if you want anyone to look at this any more you need to provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run. ScrolledComposite is always a pain to get right

Comment: Okay @greg-449. Will get back ASAP